# Nodejs combine two result of my sql commands

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have two mySql command as get result from database, i'm trying to get them with below codes but it doesn't work correctly

for example:

get results from `userEwallets` table:

```
function getMoneySenderUserInfo(data, callback) {
    var sourceEwalletNumber = data.transferToEwallet.substring(0, 5) + data.registeredMobileNumber.substring(1, data.registeredMobileNumber.length);
    var query               = "SELECT userEwallets.id as ewalletId, users.id as userId , money_repositories.money as money FROM userEwallets " +
                              "JOIN users ON users.id = userEwallets.userId " +
                              "JOIN money_repositories ON userEwallets.id = money_repositories.ewalletId " +
                              "WHERE ewalletNumber = '" + sourceEwalletNumber + "' ";
    connection.query(query, function (err, results) {
        if (err) return callback(false);

        if (results.length === 0) return callback(false);

        callback(true, results[0]);
    });
}
```

get result from `userEwallets` table again to get other result:

```
function getDestinationTakeMoneyUserInfo(data, callback) {
    var query = "SELECT users.id as userId FROM userEwallets " +
                "JOIN users ON users.id = userEwallets.userId " +
                "WHERE ewalletNumber = '" + data.transferToEwallet + "' ";
    connection.query(query, function (err, results) {
        if (err) return callback(false);

        if (results.length === 0) return callback(false);

        callback(true, results[0]);
    });
}
```

now i want to combine this results with this code:

```
usersInformation = {};
getMoneySenderUserInfo(data, function (success, result) {
    if (success) {
        usersInformation['senderId']  = result.userId;
        usersInformation['ewalletId'] = result.ewalletId;
        usersInformation['money']     = result.money;
        getDestinationTakeMoneyUserInfo(data, function (success, result) {
            usersInformation['destinationUserId'] = result.userId;
        });
    }
    log.info(usersInformation);
});
```

Comment: What library are you using to run the SQL queries? If the library supports it, you could use Promises: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise. This will allow you to chain together your queries. Or, you could use @oliv37's method.

Comment: @KennethWorden Thanks a lot sir, how can i create simple priority Queue for this functions? for example first getMoneySenderUserInfo and after finish that doing getDestinationTakeMoneyUserInfo ? on `@oliv37's `method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

I give you an example

```
function getMoneySenderUserInfo(data) {

 var promise = new Promise( function(resolve, reject) {
   var query = "..."
   connection.query(query, function (err, results) {
     if (err || results.length === 0) {
       reject();
     } else {
       resolve(results[0]);
     }
   });

 return promise;
}
```

You have to do the same thing for `getDestinationTakeMoneyUserInfo` function

Then you can have your final result like this :

```
var usersInformation = {};
Promise.all([getMoneySenderUserInfo(data), getDestinationTakeMoneyUserInfo(data)])
.then(function (results) {
    usersInformation['senderId']  = results[0].userId;
    usersInformation['ewalletId'] = results[0].ewalletId;
    usersInformation['money']     = results[0].money;
    usersInformation['destinationUserId'] = result[1].userId;
});
```

As you can see `Promise.all` will wait for the two db requests, the callback (passed in the `then` function) will be called when the two promises will be resolved so you can finally retrieve the two results.

You can also chain the promises like this :

```
getMoneySenderUserInfo(data)
.then(function (result) {
    usersInformation['senderId']  = result.userId;
    usersInformation['ewalletId'] = result.ewalletId;
    usersInformation['money']     = result.money;
    return getDestinationTakeMoneyUserInfo(data);
}).then(function (result) {
    usersInformation['destinationUserId'] = result.userId;
});
```

Comment: how can i create simple priority Queue for this functions? for example first `getMoneySenderUserInfo` and after finish that doing `getDestinationTakeMoneyUserInfo` ?

Comment: @tux-world You can chain together `Promise`s by their `.then` methods. For example, you would call `getMoneySenderUserInfo().then(function() { return getDestinationTakeMoneyUserInfo(); } ).then(function() { ... });`

Comment: as @KennethWorden said you can chain the Promises. I added it at the end of my post

Answer (score 2):

The problem you have here is that getting data from the database occurs *asynchronously*. This is why you have to use a callback function to handle the result.

Let's take, for example, your function `getMoneySenderUserInfo`. When you call it, it calls `connection.query` with your SQL query, and then *carries on* to the next instruction in that function. Then, at some point in the future after that function is completed, your SQL library receives the results of your query, and calls your callback.

Applying this to the final code, calling `log.info(usersInformation)` at the bottom of the function won't contain `destinationUserId`, because your callback hasn't been called with the results yet.

If you moved the `log.info` call into your the callback for `getDestinationTakeMoneyUserInfo`, then you would get the results you expect.

```
getMoneySenderUserInfo(data, function (success, result) {
    // This happens first
    if (success) {
        usersInformation['senderId']  = result.userId;
        usersInformation['ewalletId'] = result.ewalletId;
        usersInformation['money']     = result.money;
        getDestinationTakeMoneyUserInfo(data, function (success, result) {
            // This (probably) happens third
            usersInformation['destinationUserId'] = result.userId;
        });
    }

    // This happens second
    log.info(usersInformation);
});
```

If you're curious or want to learn more about how this all happens, check out [this fantastic video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ) by Philip Roberts.

Comment: Thank you very much as and thanks to offering youtube link, its very interesting, Unfortunately i dont have necessary to vote up your post, I'm sorry